# convert string to array | c#

Tags: c#, arrays, data-conversion

I would like to convert string "{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}" to an array. Can I do that?

I am getting data from binance.com:

```
string str = Client.DownloadString("https://" + $"api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}&startTime={startTime}&endTime={endTime}&limit={limit}");
```

And the return is something like:

```
[[1502942400000,"4261.48000000","4261.48000000","4261.48000000","4261.48000000","1.77518300",1502942459999,"7564.90685084",3,"0.07518300","320.39085084","7960.54017996"],[1502942460000,"4261.48000000","4261.48000000","4261.48000000","4261.48000000","0.00000000",1502942519999,"0.00000000",0,"0.00000000","0.00000000","7960.45262989"]]
```

I would like to convert this string to an array. I changed all '[' and ']' to '{' and '}'. Can I convert this type of string to an array?

Thanks

Comment: A string already is an array (of characters). Please clarify your question. What is the expected output?

Comment: "I would like to convert string `"{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}"` to an array." - please show the expected result for this sample string. Should it be `[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]` ?

Comment: `string[] result = str.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split(",");` Something like that? It's really not clear what you expect. Why did you change `{` to `[`, for example?

Comment: The string that is returned is in JSON. Use JSON.NET to deserialize it to an array

Comment: looks like you are confronted with a dimensional array of doubles, 
the [] outer arrays are just "syntax", the inner arrays are containing the values. just do a  str.Replace('[','{') and str.Replace(']','}')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That string is in Json format. Use the [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library to deserialize it:

```
string str = "[[1502942400000,\"4261.48000000\",\"4261.48000000\",\"4261.48000000\",\"4261.48000000\",\"1.77518300\",1502942459999,\"7564.90685084\",3,\"0.07518300\",\"320.39085084\",\"7960.54017996\"],[1502942460000,\"4261.48000000\",\"4261.48000000\",\"4261.48000000\",\"4261.48000000\",\"0.00000000\",1502942519999,\"0.00000000\",0,\"0.00000000\",\"0.00000000\",\"7960.45262989\"]]";
double[][] res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[][]>(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you are asking but this code will generate `string[] array;` that has all the elements one by one inside it.

```
string str = "{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}";
str = str.Replace("{", "");
str = str.Replace("}", "");
string[] array;
array = str.Split(',');
```

Comment: OP is receiving JSON so doing this would be a bad idea.